# Creating chart from XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

Im trying to create a line chart using information extracted from XML file. The chart intended is just simple graph consist of X and Y axis and . As we know, we can create a table using XSL stylesheet but is there a way to create a line chart ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an HTML rendering of the chart, one approach would be to use [Saxon-JS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) with XSLT/XPath to produce a JavaScript object from the XML.

The constructed object could then be converted to a chart using one of the many JavaScript plotting libraries available.

This could be done either in the browser or at the backend using NodeJS.

Answer (score 2):

If your XSLT is producing an HTML document, you can create a chart either as [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web) or a [canvas element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element).